# How can I make a request from Lambda to ECS Fargate fronted by ApplicationLoadBalancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I was able to upload the docker image into Fargate in ECS. I couldn't figure out how could my lambda make a request to ECS Fargate.

The docker image would run an application in the machine at port 8080, and we could connect to the application using localhost:8080/api/XXX in the same machine.

**Approaches I tried:**

- Make request to the domain name (https://${domainName}:8080/api/XXX) of the ApplicationLoadBalancer from Lambda
- Make request to the public/private ip address (https://${ipAddress}:8080/api/XXX) of the ApplicationLoadBalancer from Lambda

**Note**

- Domain name is set on ApplicationLoadBalancer
- Container port 8080 is set on ECS service
- Both ApplicationLoadBalancer and Lambda is inside the same VPC

Comment: Ok, but what is the issue? You have to explain exactly what is happening? What's wrong with your approaches? Any errors?

Comment: Also, how did you setup your ssl and domain, if you are trying to use `https`?